# Unable to make a phone call from PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am new to PowerApps and trying to make a Phone call to a mobile number from PowerApps by clicking on an icon.
A new browser tab (blank)is getting opened but I am not receiving any call in mobile.

Below code I tried but no luck

```
Launch("tel:\\+91 1234567890")

Launch("tel:+91 1234567890")

Launch("tel:\\91 1234567890")
Launch("tel:\\1234567890")
```

Also tried getting number from SharePoint list where mobile number added to the column "PhoneNumber"

```
Launch("tel:" & ThisItem.PhoneNumber)
Launch("tel:\\" & ThisItem.PhoneNumber)
```

Please help me to identify, what could be the issue with above code.

I am running the app from desktop browser.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: In your browser address bar, try `tel:+91 123456789` and see what happens. By the way, this doesn't automatically call the number, instead it should open the default "phone or make a call" app registered on your desktop with the number populated. Just like mailto: doesn't send an email.

Comment: When entering the number in address bar, it just bring some search result. Which app we need to install in desktop to make call? Teams will do or some other apps required?

Comment: So it is an issue with your desktop. What browser and OS are you using? (out of interest, try this `tel:+91123456789` and `tel://+91123456789`

Comment: OS is Win 10; Edge browser and as of now there is no calling app installed/configured.  Is that needed? Because, I haven't seen that as a requirement in any articles or videos referred. Above ones are also returning search results.

Comment: Of course it is required. You can't make a call without an app. You can't send an email with an app. It has been a while since using Win10, but go into (Windows) Settings, and search for "defaults by link type" or similar.

Comment: ok thanks for the info. Now I have tried entering phone number in another system and it prompts to pick the app. Looks like missing the app is the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I just test this and it's working:

```
  Launch("tel:" & ThisItem.number)
```

### Step by step:

Create a collection on the `App.OnStart` with name and number:

```
 ClearCollect( Contacts, {
    name: "jleture",
    number: "001122334455"
 });
```

[image: ClearCollect]

Create a vertical gallery with this collection:

```
Items = Contacts
```

[image: Gallery Items]

Edit the card to remove the image, assign `name` to Title and `number` to Subtitle.

[image: Vertical gallery]

Set the `OnChange` on the gallery to:

```
OnSelect = Launch("tel:" & ThisItem.number)
```

[image: OnSelect]

When clicking on the name, the browser will try to start a phone call (tested on Microsoft Edge macOS with FaceTime)

Comment: Thanks. I will try. By the way FaceTime needs to be installed on desktop for calling? Wherever I referred, only Launch() is only mentioned.

Comment: You need a `phone client` in your browser to understand the `tel:` protocol, like `mailto:` for opening a mail client. FaceTime is builtin in macOS. On Windows you can set the default app for tel: like Skype, Teams, etc.

Comment: Ok. So, I have to install teams/skype and this should work, if I understood correctly.

Comment: Yes, that's right!